# WinError 32 :The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following code to extract zip files in a directory and a delete a particular excel file in the extracted directory :

```
def extractZipFiles(dest_directory):
    "This function extracts zip files in the destination directory for further processing"
    fileFullPath = dest_directory + '\\'
    extractedDirList = list()
    for file in os.listdir(dest_directory):
        dn = fileFullPath+file
        dn = re.sub(r'\.zip$', "", fileFullPath+file) #remove the trailing .zip.
        extractedDirList.append(dn)
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(fileFullPath+file, mode='r')
        zf.extractall(dn) # extract the contents of that zip to the empty directory
        zf.close()
    return extractedDirList

def removeSelectedReports(extractedDirList):
    "This function removes the selected reports from extracted directory"
    for i in range(len(extractedDirList)):
            for filename in os.listdir(extractedDirList[i]):
                if filename.startswith("ABC_8"):
                        logger.info("File to be removed::"+filename)
                        fullPathName= "%s/%s" % (extractedDirList[i],filename)
                        os.remove(fullPathName)
    return

extractedDirList = extractZipFiles(attributionRptDestDir)
logger.info("ZIP FILES EXTRACTED:"+str(extractedDirList))
removeSelectedReports(extractedDirList)
```

I am getting the following intermittent issue even though **I have closed the zip file handler**.

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '\\\\share\\Workingdirectory\\report.20180517.zip'
```

Can you please help resolve this issue

Comment: Full Error Stack, please.

Comment: I don't any error in the log file apart from WinError32

Answer (score 0):

You should try to figure out what has the file open. Based on your code, it looks like you are on Microsoft Windows.

I would stop all applications on your workstation, including browsers, run with only a minimum number of apps open, and reproduce the problem. Once reproduced you can use a tool to lists all handles open to a particular file.

A handy utility would be [handle.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle), but please use any tool with similar functionality.

Once you find the offending application, you can further investigate why the file is open, and take counter measures.

I would be careful not to close any application which has the file open, until you know it is safe to do so.

Comment: I checked only 1 python process is running

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer the question, nor does it follow the answer I have given; how about other processes on your machine... they may have a handle open to your file ... ??

Comment: I executed for p in psutil.process_iter() code to list the processes running. But how to find the process that has handle open to my file?

Comment: @Karthik did you run handle.exe ?

Comment: I am executing this script on autosys VM. Handle is not installed on that machine.Is there any other way to find the same in python?

Comment: @Karthik you are on Windows, as you get a `[WinError 32]`. **THE** tool for the last 20 years to troubleshoot open handles on Windows is `handle.exe`. How you run this tool on your Virtual Machine is really outside scope here. May I suggest you post a new question to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) to get answers on how to troubleshoot your particular infrastructure